# UIScrollView or custom drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uiscrollview

I am facing the following problem in my current project: I want to implement something like the following:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGVaryingGridView

Since I have to draw an EPG for maybe 40 Stations or more for maybe a week, my question is: Should I fill a UIScrollView with many many subviews (representing the shows) or is it better for the performance if I draw one big UIView using Quartz2D and then add it as a single subview of the UIScrollView?

Hope you could follow me,
Thanks in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure i understand, but you can create a ViewQueue where subviews can be reused, like a **UITableView**:

Everytime you need a **UIView**, you ask the Queue(**NSMutableArray**) to get an existing view. If the Queue is empty create a new UIView, if it already contains views, (re)use an existing UIView stored in the Queue.

Only if the UIView should be visible add it to screen (**UIView** retrieved from Queue), if its not visible anymore remove it from its superview and add it to the Queue.

You can then use a **UIScrollView** to show the subviews. If your scrolling you can just set the UIScrollView size to make it larger and smaller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But having that queue, I still have all the views in memory, isn't it?

Comment: You will save lots of memory; Check instruments, if you store them in a mutablearray vs drawing them all on a screen. Besides that theres no need to draw objects that are outside of the screen bounds. Just make sure you remove the UIView from it superview when there outside of the screen bounds